# Pandas count past identical occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this.

```
   col1  col2  Col3  target
    1     3     7      0
    2     4     8      1
    1     3     7      1
    2     4     8      0
    1     3     7      1
    2     4     8      0
    1     3     7      1 
    2     4     8      1
    1     3     7      1
    2     4     8      1
    2     4     8      0
    1     3     7      0
    2     4     8      0
    1     3     7      0
```

I would like to count the past identical target occurrences.

For example, if the current row target is `1` and the last 3 row target `1` as well, then I would like to have the value `3` in the count column.

More examples:

Current row target is `1`; Last row target is `0`; Count is `0`.

Current row target is `1`; Last row target is `1`; Count is `1`.

Current row target is `1`; Last 2 row target is `1`; Count is `2`.

Current row target is `0`; Last 2 row target is `0`; Count is `2`.

This is how the modified df looks like.

```
   col1  col2  Col3  target  count
    1     3     7      0      0
    2     4     8      1      0
    1     3     7      1      1
    2     4     8      0      0
    1     3     7      1      0
    2     4     8      0      0
    1     3     7      1      0
    2     4     8      1      1
    1     3     7      1      2
    2     4     8      1      3
    2     4     8      0      0
    1     3     7      0      1
    2     4     8      0      2
    1     3     7      0      3
```

Is there any easier way to do this in pandas?

Comment: `df['count'] = df['target'].groupby(df['target'].ne(df['target'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with consecutive groups created by compared shifted values:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df['target'].ne(df['target'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()

print (df)
    col1  col2  Col3  target  count
0      1     3     7       0      0
1      2     4     8       1      0
2      1     3     7       1      1
3      2     4     8       0      0
4      1     3     7       1      0
5      2     4     8       0      0
6      1     3     7       1      0
7      2     4     8       1      1
8      1     3     7       1      2
9      2     4     8       1      3
10     2     4     8       0      0
11     1     3     7       0      1
12     2     4     8       0      2
13     1     3     7       0      3
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['target'].ne(df['target'].shift()).cumsum())
0     1
1     2
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6
7     6
8     6
9     6
10    7
11    7
12    7
13    7
Name: target, dtype: int32
```